# What's the difference in CPUID work on 32-bit and 64-bit machines?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, 32bit-64bit, cpuid

My question is what is the difference in `CPUID` work on 32-bit and 64-bit machines? Maybe there are some differences in the way we call `CPUID` or the way it returns the result, like, we should check `RAX` and other registers, maybe the information stored in them is different

Answer (score 3):

according to [Intel SDM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-sdm-combined-volumes-1-2a-2b-2c-2d-3a-3b-3c-3d-and-4)

> the instruction is operate the same for both 64b and non-64b

but even though that it's behave the same, keep in mind that CPUID instruction clears the high 32 bits of the RAX/RBX/RCX/RDX registers in all modes, so if you check the highest 32 bits in the registers mention above you will read 0x0.

And since CPUID is looking at EAX (and ECX in some cases) both codes below will return same data :

`mov RAX, 0xFFFF_FFFF_0000_000`
`cpuid`

`mov RAX, 0x0`
`cpuid`

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cpuid has instruction listings scraped from Intel's PDFs.  [Writing a 32-bit register *always* zero-extends to the full 64-bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6), including when CPUID writes them.  (As you say, even in 32-bit mode and then you later switch to 64-bit mode so you can read the full regs)